# Как просмотреть исходный код Math.random?

Tags: javascript

Math.random это метод в javascript, и я хотел бы знать, как он выглядит внутри.

Comment: https://v8.dev/blog/math-random

Comment: Какой-то чувак задал такой же вопрос на другом форуме 10 лет назад (!). И ему до сих пор не ответили

Comment: реализация этого метода в каждой среде выполнения своя

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию @Igor. В V8 Math.random реализован на C++, вот [исходник текущей реализации](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/builtins/builtins-math-gen.cc#L402)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так выглядит реализация в v8

```
uint32_t V8::Random() {
 // Random number generator using George Marsaglia's MWC algorithm.
 static uint32_t hi = 0;
 static uint32_t lo = 0;
 // Initialize seed using the system random(). If one of the seeds
 // should ever become zero again, or if random() returns zero, we
 // avoid getting stuck with zero bits in hi or lo by reinitializing
 // them on demand.
 if (hi == 0) hi = random();
 if (lo == 0) lo = random();
 // Mix the bits.
 hi = 36969 * (hi & 0xFFFF) + (hi >> 16);
 lo = 18273 * (lo & 0xFFFF) + (lo >> 16);
 return (hi << 16) + (lo & 0xFFFF);
}
```

Ссылка на подробное описание - [тыц](https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/papers/general/Google_Chrome_3.0_Beta_Math.random_vulnerability.pdf)

Comment: [Уже нет](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/builtins/builtins-math-gen.cc#L402)